# How do I use a Foundation close link with rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation

Rails 4.2
Ruby 2.2.0

In my layout:

```
<div class="alert-box warning">
  Flash message goes here 
  <a href="#" class="close">×</a>
</div>
```

But the "x" doesn't hide (or close) the div.  It just takes the browser to the same URL with an '#' appended.  In other words, the Foundation close js is never executed.

How do I make the link with a close class work?

Comment: Have you checked the Javascript you include if there is a function to do this? Are you using the correct classes? The Foundation doc says you need to have `data-alert` in the div.

Comment: It was the missing data-alert.  Make this an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `div` is missing the `data-alert` attribute. Example in the [documentation](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/alert_boxes.html):

```
<div data-alert class="alert-box">
  <!-- Your content goes here -->
  <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your foundation settings, you can set a class that will be clicked in order to close a modal.

```
$(document).foundation({
     reveal: { 
         dismiss_modal_class: 'close'
     }
});
```